# How do I make the countdown to show "Happy New Year 2021" when the day comes?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a simple countdown clock for New Year 2021 using C#, after so many different ways, it either show the message in this year instead of next year or not showing anything on 1/1, and went straight to countdown. I want it to show "Happy New Year 2021" at midnight 1/1 and everything goes back to normal after the day end. Here is the code that I'm having trouble with, I also have the countdown for Christmas and it worked great, but not this one. I'm not sure if this is correct or I'm missing something. Thank you.

```
        DateTime starttime1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime newyear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year+1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime afterNewyear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0);
         if (starttime1 < newyear)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }            
        else if (starttime1 >= dayAfterNewyear && starttime1 <= dayAfterNewyear)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            label1.Text = "Happy New Year 2021";
        }
        else {
            //start the countdown again for next year//   
        }
```

Comment: Timezones are important, I'd recommend using DateTimeOffset. Or at least specify the DateTime.Kind explicitly.

Comment: Do not add _"[SOLVED]"_ or similar artifacts to the titles of Stack Overflow posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, I didn't run your code, but I suspect that the issue is the comparison you're doing with afterNewyear

```
if ((newyear - starttime1).TotalDays  > 0)//if newyear hasn't been reached
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else if (Math.Abs((starttime1-newyear).TotalDays) < 1)//If currently if the new year day
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            label1 = "Happy New Year 2021";
        }
        else
        {
            //start the countdown again for next year//   
        }
```